# Edge captions in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to add text captions on edges but I can't make it work.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,-]

\tikzstyle{vertex}=[circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt]                   
\foreach \name/\angle/\text in {P-0/234/0, P-1/162/1, 
                                P-2/90/2, P-3/18/3, P-4/-54/4}
  \node[vertex,xshift=6cm,yshift=.5cm] (\name) at (\angle:1.5cm) {$\text$};

\foreach \from/\to in {0/4, 4/1,1/2,2/4,0/3}
 { 
  \draw (P-\from) -- (P-\to);
 }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Could someone help me?
Thanks!

Comment: What do you want on the edge?

Comment: For example text: "e_1" and so on

Comment: It's good that you mark your code block. It's even better if you indent by just 4 spaces (and use only a bit of further indentation).

Comment: @Hendrik: I had the code indented with more spaces and I was looking for a way how to "unintend" the block of text when asking the question? Or do I need to do that in an external text editor?

Comment: You had a lot of tab stops in it. The best way is to insert the code without any extra indentation (and without any tab stops); then highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "101010" on it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example, `\draw (P-\from) -- node {\from\ to \to} (P-\to);`
And you can use more options to change the style:

```
\draw (P-\from) -- node[auto,sloped,font=\footnotesize] {\from\ to \to} (P-\to);
```